# Firebase get key string of a push

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

I am doing a push action with setValue.

```
mFirebaseDatabaseReference.child("loccheck").push().setValue(cloc);
```

How do I retrieve the unique string created?
P.S. I know how to do it with a push without setValue:

```
String key = mDatabase.child("posts").push().getKey();
```

Comment: Maybe you can split your calls to two separate lines? First perform the push, then set the desired value.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You can get the unique key after you push like

```
DatabaseReference newDatabaseReference = mDatabaseReference.child("loccheck").push();
newDatabaseReference.getKey();
```

or with `setValue()`

```
mDatabaseReference.child("loccheck")
        .push()
        .setValue(cloc, new DatabaseReference.CompletionListener() {
            @Override
            public void onComplete(DatabaseError databaseError,
                    DatabaseReference databaseReference) {
                 String uniqueKey = databaseReference.getKey();
            }
        });
```

Comment: You don't have to setValue() on the push() in order to get the key.  You can just call getKey() immediately on Reference returned from push().

Comment: @DougStevenson thank you for teach me a new thing. I have update it to my answer. Does it look better?

Comment: Why dont it require an Internet connection. Can another user get the same key?

Comment: @Trk sorry, I don't understand your question? can you explain it more?

Comment: Do you need internet connection to get the key?