# Firebase Functions receive Object instead of String

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-realtime-database, firebase-cloud-messaging

Bear with me. I've spent a month just PHRASING this question:  I've been using Firebase Database and Firebase functions for about a year. I've gotten it to work... but only if I sent the text of the message as a STRING. The problem is that now I wish to receive an OBJECT instead but I'm unsure of how to do this in FireBaseMessage.

My previous structure:

```
messages
   T9Vh5cvUcbqC8IEZowBpJC3
      ZWfn7876876ZGJeSNBbCpPmkm1
           message



"messages": {
        ".read": true,
      "$receiverUid": {
        "$senderUid": {
          "$message": {
            ".read": true,
            ".write": "auth.uid === $senderUid"
```

And my function for the listener was this:

```
exports.sendMessage = functions.database.ref('/messages/{receiverUid}/{senderUid}/{message}')
```

This is problematic... for a variety of reasons. Namely if the old message was "Hey" and then that same person just writes "Hey" again... then the original gets overwritten.

So my NEW structure is more like this:

```
messages
  -LkVcYqJoEroWpkXZnqr
      body: "genius grant"
      createdat: 1563915599253
      name: "hatemustdie"
      receiverUid: "TW8289372984KJjkhdsjkhad"
      senderUid: "yBNbs9823789KJkjahsdjkas"
```

Which is written as:

```
mDatabase.child("messages").push().setValue(message);
```

...and I'm just unsure about how to write out that function.

I mean... IDEALLY... it would be something like:

```
exports.sendMessage = functions.database.ref('/messages/{receiverUid}/{senderUid}/{msgID}/{msgOBJECT}')
```

...but I'm just not sure how Firebase functions is reading this new structure.

Now I'm pushing to the database like so:

```
mDatabase.child("messages").child(guid).child(user_Id).push().setValue(msgObject).addOnSuccessListener(this, new OnSuccessListener<Void>() {
                                @Override
                                public void onSuccess(@NonNull Void T) {
                                    Log.d("MessageActivity", "Message Sent");
```

Basically I would just like to receive the message object... with everything in it... when it arrives from the notification... and be able to easily parse the body, date, userids, etc.

Can someone explain the correct way to go about this?

**UPATE** By request here's the complete cloud function:

```
exports.sendMessage = functions.database.ref('/messages/{receiverUid}/{senderUid}/{msgId}/{message}')
    .onWrite(async (change, context) => {
      const message = context.params.message;
      // const messageId = context.params.messageId;
      const receiverUid = context.params.receiverUid;
      const senderUid = context.params.senderUid;
      // If un-follow we exit the function.
      if (!change.after.val()) {
        return console.log('Sender ', senderUid, 'receiver ', receiverUid, 'message ', message);
      }
      console.log('We have a new message: ', message, 'for: ', receiverUid);

      // Get the list of device notification tokens.
      const getDeviceTokensPromise = admin.database()
          .ref(`/users/${receiverUid}/notificationTokens`).once('value');

      // Get the follower profile.
      const getSenderProfilePromise = admin.auth().getUser(senderUid);

      // The snapshot to the user's tokens.
      let tokensSnapshot;

      // The array containing all the user's tokens.
      let tokens;

      const results = await Promise.all([getDeviceTokensPromise, getSenderProfilePromise]);
      tokensSnapshot = results[0];
      const sender = results[1];

        // Check if there are any device tokens.
        if (!tokensSnapshot.hasChildren()) {
          return console.log('There are no notification tokens to send to.');
        }
        console.log('There are', tokensSnapshot.numChildren(), 'tokens to send notifications to.');
        console.log('Fetched sender profile', sender);
//        console.log('David you're looking for the following UID:', followerUid);

        // Notification details.
        const payload = {
          notification: {
            title: `${sender.displayName} sent you a message.`,
            body: message,
            tag: senderUid
          },
        //  'data': { 'fuid': followerUid }
          data: { 
            type: 'message', 
            name: sender.displayName
          }
        };
      console.log('David you are looking for the following message:', message);
        // Listing all tokens as an array.
      tokens = Object.keys(tokensSnapshot.val());
      // Send notifications to all tokens.
      const response = await admin.messaging().sendToDevice(tokens, payload);
      // For each message check if there was an error.
      const tokensToRemove = [];
      response.results.forEach((result, index) => {
        const error = result.error;
        if (error) {
          console.error('Failure sending notification to', tokens[index], error);
          // Cleanup the tokens who are not registered anymore.
          if (error.code === 'messaging/invalid-registration-token' ||
              error.code === 'messaging/registration-token-not-registered') {
            tokensToRemove.push(tokensSnapshot.ref.child(tokens[index]).remove());
          }
        }
      });
        return Promise.all(tokensToRemove);
  });
```

Comment: Show your complete cloud function

Comment: Just pasted it above. @YashKrishan

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since you now store the sender and receiver's UIDs inside the message, the declaration of your Cloud Function will need to change.

Instead of this:

```
exports.sendMessage = functions.database.ref('/messages/{receiverUid}/{senderUid}/{msgId}/{message}').onWrite(async (change, context) => {
```

You'll need to trigger on:

```
exports.sendMessage = functions.database.ref('/messages/{messageId}').onWrite(async (change, context) => {
```

So with this change your code will trigger on each message that is written `/messages`.

Now you "just" need to get the sender and receiver's UID. And since you no longer can get them from the `context`, you will instead get them from the `change`. Specifically `change.after` contains the data snapshot as it exists in the database *after* the write has completed. So (as long as you're not deleting the data), you can get the UIDs with:

```
const receiverUid = change.after.val().receiverUid;
const senderUid = change.after.val().senderUid;
```

And you'll also get the actual message from there of course:

```
const message = change.after.val().message;
```

And just in case you need the message ID (the `-L...` key that it was written under in the database):

```
const messageId = change.after.val().messageId;
```

Comment: Wow... I have NO IDEA how everyone else figured this out. Checking now. Will report back in a bit!

Comment: @YashKrishan Your solution is also correct, hence my upvote to it. I merely had typed a bit more by the time we both hit enter. :)

Comment: @mysticcola I get most of this info from the [documentation on Realtime Database triggers](https://firebase.google.com/docs/functions/database-events), and by looking at the [`functions-samples` repo](https://github.com/firebase/functions-samples), which is a treasure trove of great code samples.

Comment: Completely understood and thanks. However, I am in doubt about the way OP was structuring the object in RTD. Is this the right way to structure it in so many layers : /messages/{receiverUid}/{senderUid}/{msgId}/{message} ?

Comment: I have a feeling that it is definitely not a good practice. Reducing layers helps more in handling data in formats like JSON.

Comment: Doesn't this mean that I would have to change the java as well? (mDatabase.child("messages").child(guid).child(user_Id).push().setValue(message)) And, possibly, also the database structure as defined above? Or no?

Comment: @YashKrishan Correct. That why I removed the two in-between layers (`receiverUid` and `senderId`) *and* that lowest layer (`message`). That last one would just cause additional triggers, because you're essentially listening to the individual properties.

Comment: @mysticcola Yes, you would have to change your Java code to write the database structure that you indicated in "So my NEW structure is more like this:" in your question.

Comment: @FrankvanPuffelen Yeah I just didn't actually know how to write that when I wrote the question. :) I eventually went with: mDatabase.child("messages").push().setValue(message)

Answer (score 1):

You need a trigger on just the messageId:

```
exports.sendMessage = functions.database.ref('/messages/{messageId}').onWrite((change, context) => {
      const changedData = change.after.val(); // This will have the complete changed data
      const message = change.after.val().message;  // This will contain the message value
      ......
});
```

Elaborating on Frank's answer:
You can't get the data from context like `const message = context.params.message;`because those parameters don't exists anymore on the context.

Comment: Doesn't this mean that I would have to change the java as well? (mDatabase.child("messages").child(guid).child(user_Id).push().setValue(message)) And, possibly, also the database structure as defined above?

Comment: No I guess not because you've already modified that code to fit the new format.

Comment: I changed it to "mDatabase.child("messages").push().setValue(message)". It's a little bit cleaner. Plus it matches better to: functions.database.ref('/messages/{messageId}'). Thanks for all your help!

Comment: You wouldn't happen to know how to get the id from "push()" would you? It was working before... but now mDatabase2 = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference("messages");  mDatabase2.getKey() only returns "messages" and not the actual key.

Comment: One way to do it is first store the key like this: https://stackoverflow.com/a/43362516/8259771

Then use it.